# How to prevent redirecting to subdomain when enter url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is confusing to explain, but I am rewriting urls for a router/framework I am making. I am directing my root to a folder named public and in that folder I handle the rewriting for index.php and such. But I want to be able to access css and a js folder. Anyways, whenever I go to /css it will take me to /public/css and lets me view files and lists directory but when I view a file it lets me view the file without changing the URL. So basically, if someone goes to /css I want it to stay like that, and not be changed to /public/css.

root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

public .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your root .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|css|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Now this rewrite rule won't affect `/css/` and `/js/` folders.